# blackberry stops responding to javaloader -usb after a period of inactivity

Tags: blackberry

Has anyone experienced this issue -

Blackberry stops responding to javaloader -usb after a period of inactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this problem by killing the bbdevmgr process from Windows TaskManager and then re-launching Blackberry Desktop Manager (upon which the BB promptly wakes up and starts responding to javaloader). Yay!!